# Client side validation with Spring MVC <form:errors> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, spring-mvc

I want to apply client side validation (using JavaScript or jQuery). If validation fails, I want to populate the `<form:errors path="firstName">` tag of Spring MVC. Is this possible? Server side validations are working fine.

For example, with a jsp snippet like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="student">
    ...
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="20">
    <form:errors path="firstName">
</form:form>
```

I would like to be able to manipulate the `form:errors` label with client-side JavaScript code, something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    if(firstName.value==null || firstName.value=="") {
        //here I want to populate the <form:errors> tag
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Client-side validation is more for usability - and yes you can permeate out the server-side response when you're client validation is bypassed. The issue is, it's easy to bypass client-side validation. Please post a code example?

Comment: `
function validateForm() {
   if(firstName.value==null || firstName.value=="") {
       **//here I want to populate the <form:errors> tag**
       return;
    }
}

**jsp file**
<form:form method="POST" commandName="student">
...
   <label>First Name:</label>
   <form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="20">
   <form:errors path="firstName">
</form:form>
`

Comment: Can you please update your question with an MCVE?